# How to get the content from a page whose url calls an api with PHP

Tags: php, url, mediawiki, file-get-contents, mediawiki-api

I intend to get the content from a page. 
I used file_get_contents() to get the content, but failed. Nothing showed in the browser.

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&titles=firstPage&format=xml&prop=info&inprop=watched");
```

Actually, the link above can show the information about the page of firsrPage in xml.

How can I get the contents from the url which calls an api?

Comment: What happens when you try to visit the URL manually on your browser?

Comment: The link above can show a xml file which includes the information about the page called firstPage. I want to get the information. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not available via your web browser, then `file_get_contents` won't be able to fetch the contents either. Try to find out why the first URL isn't returning the XML -- and fix that first.

Comment: The URL can return a xml file and show in the browser. I want to get the content of this file and search for some certain information. But I don't know how to get the content through this URL. The function file_get_contents() can't work.

Answer (score 0):

here you can use CURL to get elements from your API Link, using CURL give you more options to get elements from a file, you can also use file_get_contents() with a context() which will get the elemnts from your link, but i perefer the curl.

```
$url = 'API_URL'

 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

 $result=curl_execute($ch);
 if(!$result){
 exit ('cURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch));
 }
 var_dump($result);
```

else you can try this:

```
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
echo file_get_html('your url')->plaintext;
```